# etc/profile/ loading error Flatpack involved

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade

In the process of upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04 (with 18.04 first), I tried to update everything, but did fail to update Flatpak packages. I'm not familiar with what flatpak does.

Now I have a start up error message recommending upgrade from 16.04 because 'packages on the Flatpack ppa for Ubuntu 16.04 will not necessarily be updated'. This was on the first boot up with Ubuntu 20.04.

I don't understand this and would like help on hopefully easy steps to fix it.
Also Wine did not install because of broken packages. And I think my keyboard is wonky! Toshiba C-55 dual boot with win8

Comment: `etc/profile/` needs a `/` in front of it.  I would remove the flatpak ppa and find a newer one. That should fix this issue(?)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do I need to apt get flatpak or something to replace?